# ProgressDialog Error

Tags: android

Hy my code:

```
           package com.android.skiptvad;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.skiptvad.*;

public class Login extends Activity {
    private static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tvuser;
    String sessionid;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);


        tvuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvuser);
        TextView tvpw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvpw);
        final EditText etuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etuser);
        final EditText etpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpw);
        Button btlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        btlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (etuser.getText() != null && etpw.getText()!= null)
                {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
                    try
                    {
                    //download(etuser.getText().toString(), md5(etpw.getText().toString()));
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                    String postURL = "http://surfkid.redio.de/login";
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", etuser.getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", md5(etpw.getText().toString())));
                        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                        post.setEntity(ent);

                        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                        final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                        JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("responseData");

                        if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 200 && jObject.get("responseDetails")!= null)
                        {
                            sessionid = menuObject.getString("session_id");


                        }   

                        else
                        {

                             if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 500)
                             {
                                 throw new Exception("Server Error");
                             }
                             else if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 400)
                             {
                                 throw new Exception("Wrong User/Password");
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 throw new Exception();
                             }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("error", "error");
                    }
                    finally{
                        dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public void download (final String user, final String pw)
    {



    }
    private String md5(String in) {

        MessageDigest digest;

        try {

            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            digest.reset();        

            digest.update(in.getBytes());

            byte[] a = digest.digest();

            int len = a.length;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));

                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));

            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOADING:
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            ((ProgressDialog) dialog).setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
            break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }




}
```

No Dialog appears!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform updates to the UI directly from a background thread.

If you absolutely must use a `Thread`, then you can get it to work using `onCreateDialog` to prepare the new dialog.  You then call `showDialog(int)` and `dismissDialog(int)` to show/hide the dialog:

```
private static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 0;

...
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_LOADING:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ((ProgressDialog) dialog).setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

btlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (etuser.getText() != null && etpw.getText()!= null)
        {
            showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        download(etuser.getText().toString(), md5(etpw.getText().toString()));
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TAG","Exception caught in thread:"+e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try{
                            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            Log.w("TAG","Dialog does not exist");
                        }
                    }
                    //finish();  
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried your code, but the dismiss is not working, the dialog is shown always

Comment: Does it throw an exception in the log?

Comment: I've updated the code to added better exception handling, perhaps you can retest?

Comment: You have `dismissDialog()` in both the `if` and `else` blocks.  I would add a `finally` block to the `try`/`catch` within your `run()` method and use the `dismissDialog()` format from my code above, where it is wrapped in its own `try`/`catch` that logs a failure to close the dialog.  If you make these changes, re-run the code and let us know what error are written to the log.

Comment: thx for your help i updated the code but no dialog appears. My Project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7225753/SkipTvAd.zip No error occurs

Comment: if your code above is accurate, then you haven't yet implemented my suggestions.  Please remove the `dismissDialog()` calls from the `if` and `else` block and wrap the `dismissDialog()` call in the `finally` block with its own `try`/`catch`.  Please refer to my above code for an example.  In short, the only place to perform the `dismissDialog()` call is within the `finally` block.

Comment: Since it was showing the dialog earlier when you had the `Thread` defined within the `onClick` method, and now that you have refactored to move the code out into its own method it no longer shows the dialog, I'm thinking this is the cause.  If you move the code within `download` back into `onClick` I'll bet it will show the dialog.

Comment: Also, you are running the `Thread` in the UI thread, so its going to block the creation of dialog.  Start the thread as a background thread rather than running in the UI.

Comment: new update..... not working.... please download my project. I am at my wit's end.

Comment: So now you have removed the `Thread`... at this point I would debug it, either step through with the debugger or add some `Log.d("Login","some text");` messages liberally through the code to see what's going on.

Comment: please help debugg me.... i can debugg in c# and normal java but in the android sdk... i set a breakpoint and press f11 and if the code should be at the breakpoint nothing happend...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a UI-related API function outside the UI thread - in this case, presumably `pd.dismiss()`. Anything that has to do with the UI needs to run on the main thread - an easy way to accomplish that is via `Activity.runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @EboMike, and whatever you tried was probably wrong.

But my suggestion is, you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) It's a far cleaner way of doing what you are trying to do.